# YouTube speed increase only works in Firefox, not on Chrome or Opera

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, youtube, opera

I recently started to watch some videos, and I want to watch them at 1.25x speed or 1.5x speed.

When I try this on Chrome or Opera the video lags, freezes and it is impossible to watch. But on Firefox it works perfectly fine.

Is there anything I can do to to make the speed increase work well on Chrome and Opera as it does on Firefox?

Comment: OS and versions of browsers?

Comment: I am running Windows 7.

Comment: And the browser versions? What videos are you using to test?

Comment: i will post when i go back home. the videos do not make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that variable speed controls are **only available in HTML5**. *Flash* fallback will not offer you such option. Right-click on a *YouTube* video and see whether context menu you get is from *Flash* (you can see *Flash* version etc.) or HTML5 (black background). This would be an important hint to find a solution for the problem.

For unknown reasons (right now) your *Opera* and *Chrome* may be using *Flash* fallback while your *Firefox* is using HTML5. That would explain this behavior.

Of course, I cannot be sure if this is what is happening but check it out.